# Unable to upgrade from 10.1 to 10.2

Tags: composer

I've been using Composer from the start and have had no problem upgrading Drupal as it went, but somehow it refuses to upgrade from 10.1.8 to 10.2.

In my composer.json I have `"drupal/core-recommended": "^10",`

If I run `composer update "drupal/core-*" --with-all-dependencies`, it tells me there's nothing to update.

So in changed composer.json to `"drupal/core-recommended": "^10.2.2",`

And now when I run composer it tells me *"drupal/core 10.2.2 conflicts with drupal/core 10.2.2"*

Any idea what's going on?

Edit - here are more details:

**with "drupal/core-recommended": "^10"**

command:

```
composer update "drupal/core-*" --with-all-dependencies
```

output:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating optimized autoload files
```

command:

```
composer why-not drupal/core-recommended 10.2.2
```

output:

```
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          drupal/core (10.2.2)                                        
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  drupal/core (but 10.1.8 is installed)                       
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          asm89/stack-cors (~v2.2.0)                                  
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  asm89/stack-cors (but v2.1.1 is installed)                  
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          composer/semver (~3.4.0)                                    
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  composer/semver (but 3.3.2 is installed)                    
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          guzzlehttp/guzzle (~7.8.1)                                  
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  guzzlehttp/guzzle (but 7.7.1 is installed)                  
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          guzzlehttp/psr7 (~2.6.2)                                    
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  guzzlehttp/psr7 (but 2.5.1 is installed)                    
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/console (~v6.4.1)                                   
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/console (but v6.3.11 is installed)                  
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/dependency-injection (~v6.4.1)                      
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/dependency-injection (but v6.3.11 is installed)     
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/deprecation-contracts (~v3.4.0)                     
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/deprecation-contracts (but v3.3.0 is installed)     
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/error-handler (~v6.4.0)                             
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/error-handler (but v6.3.5 is installed)             
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/event-dispatcher (~v6.4.0)                          
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/event-dispatcher (but v6.3.11 is installed)         
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (~v3.4.0)                
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (but v3.3.0 is installed)
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/http-foundation (~v6.4.0)                           
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/http-foundation (but v6.3.11 is installed)          
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/http-kernel (~v6.4.1)                               
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/http-kernel (but v6.3.11 is installed)              
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/mime (~v6.4.0)                                      
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/mime (but v6.3.5 is installed)                      
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/polyfill-ctype (~v1.28.0)                           
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/polyfill-ctype (but v1.27.0 is installed)           
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/polyfill-iconv (~v1.28.0)                           
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/polyfill-iconv (but v1.27.0 is installed)           
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (~v1.28.0)                   
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (but v1.27.0 is installed)   
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (~v1.28.0)                        
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (but v1.27.0 is installed)        
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (~v1.28.0)                 
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (but v1.27.0 is installed) 
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/polyfill-mbstring (~v1.28.0)                        
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/polyfill-mbstring (but v1.27.0 is installed)        
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/polyfill-php83 (~v1.28.0)                           
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/polyfill-php83 (but v1.27.0 is installed)           
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/process (~v6.4.0)                                   
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/process (but v6.3.11 is installed)                  
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (~v6.4.0)                   
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (but v2.2.0 is installed)   
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/routing (~v6.4.1)                                   
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/routing (but v6.3.11 is installed)                  
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/serializer (~v6.4.1)                                
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/serializer (but v6.3.11 is installed)               
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/service-contracts (~v3.4.0)                         
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/service-contracts (but v3.3.0 is installed)         
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/string (~v6.4.0)                                    
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/string (but v6.3.11 is installed)                   
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/translation-contracts (~v3.4.0)                     
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/translation-contracts (but v3.3.0 is installed)     
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/validator (~v6.4.0)                                 
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/validator (but v6.3.11 is installed)                
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/var-dumper (~v6.4.0)                                
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/var-dumper (but v6.3.11 is installed)               
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/var-exporter (~v6.4.1)                              
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/var-exporter (but v6.3.11 is installed)             
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          symfony/yaml (~v6.4.0)                                      
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  symfony/yaml (but v6.3.8 is installed)                      
drupal/core-recommended     10.2.2      requires          twig/twig (~v3.8.0)                                         
drupal/recommended-project  dev-master  does not require  twig/twig (but v3.6.1 is installed)
```

**with "drupal/core-recommended": "10.2.2"**

command:

```
composer update "drupal/core-*" --with-all-dependencies
```

output:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended 10.2.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.2.2].   
    - drupal/core 10.2.2 conflicts with drupal/core 10.2.2.
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.2.2 requires drupal/core 10.2.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.2.2].
    - drush/drush is locked to version 11.6.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

Comment: If you were to share the full command and all the command output perhaps we could answer.

Comment: We also require the output of `composer why-not drupal/core-recommended 10.2.2`. These tips are documented on Drupal.org and in Composer’s documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I've now added the full command and output in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  ...
  - drush/drush is locked to version 11.6.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

See the release notes of Drupal 10.2.x:

> ### Drush versions below 12.4.3 are incompatible with Drupal 10.2.x
>
> - Users of Drush will need to upgrade to version 12.4.3 or greater.

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/10.2.0

Comment: Ah, thank you, it turned out that composer couldn't install the latest version of Drush because I needed to update composer to the latest version. After that it all worked out.